# JDBC dao and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, jdbc, dao

Let's say I have 2 classes in my model :

```
public class Account {
  int capital;
  int numero
  }

public class SavingAccount extends Account{
  double rate;  
}
```

So when I have to save or retrieve an account in a database using JDBC, it works but for the binding it is OK for capital and numero but for rate I need to check the type and cast it :

```
if(account.getType() ==  AccountType.SAVINGACCOUNT) {
((SavingAccount)Account).setRate(result.getDouble("rate"));
}
```

Is it possible to do otherwise than that or than have 2 different methods ?

Answer (score 0):

The last and just-before-implementation class is the `SavingAccount`. SavingAcccount contains `rate's getter and setter` methods. So, whenever you use `getRate()`, you should type cast your Account to `SavingAccount`, because in the heap space of `SavingAccount` you have `getRate()` method.

Because the final implementation is via `SavingAccount`, you also provide via TypeChecking `AccountType.SAVINGACCOUNT` for the correct database transactions.

When you do your executions via `Account` instance, it gives you polymorphic power. That's why it's important.

So, in your scenario, I don't see any other solution exists. You are doing  good.